# How return a value from one class function to another class function in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get the value of a varibale if a condition is tru from one class function to another class function.

Could you please let me know how do i do this(I am new to PHP.)

Code:

```
class ErrorList{
static function getErrorsSince($delay, $criteria = NULL) {
        global $appsFeXref, $table_error,$table_error_dis, $table_occurrence, $table_status, $table_fe_parameters, $debugMode;

        if ($criteria->isValid()){
            $var1 = '123';
         }
}

Class  Error{

             function initFromDb($initDetails = false) {
        global $appsFeXref, $table_error, $table_status, $table_fe_parameters, $table_error_dis;
        $details = ($initDetails)? ", s.last_time, s.last_time_origin, s.last_time_machine, s.last_time_text, s.last_time_peak, ed.comment ":"";
        $test = $var1;
         echo "$test";

}
```

Here you can see I need `$var1` variable value from `ErrorList` class to `Error` class.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Tejesh.B

Comment: Check out this tutorial: http://www.techflirt.com/tutorials/oop-in-php/static-methods-and-properties-in-php.html. Note that you probably don't need to be using static properties and methods to begin with in this case, but hopefully that tutorial will help you understand what static members are for.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
class ErrorList{
static function getErrorsSince($delay, $criteria = NULL) {
        global $appsFeXref, $table_error,$table_error_dis, $table_occurrence, $table_status, $table_fe_parameters, $debugMode;

        if ($criteria->isValid()){
            $var1 = '123';
            return $var1;
         }
}
}
class  Error{

             function initFromDb($initDetails = false) {
        global $appsFeXref, $table_error, $table_status, $table_fe_parameters, $table_error_dis;
        $details = ($initDetails)? ", s.last_time, s.last_time_origin, s.last_time_machine, s.last_time_text, s.last_time_peak, ed.comment ":"";
      $call_class = new ErrorList();
      $get_val = $call_class->getErrorsSince();
        $test = $get_val;
         echo $test;

}
}

 ?>
```

Comment: your code is right but static function(method) of  class direct used like echo ErrorList::getErrorsSince();